# Detect widget change in QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a GUI that is to be put on a screen that has hardware buttons which map onto function keys. When a top row key is pressed the idea is that the screen will change to a different view of the data with the side buttons mapping into the view currently displayed and displaying corresponding information on screen (button, or label).

I have a top-level widget that contains these buttons and a stacked widget with the different data view (widgets) inside. I can navigate within the stacked widget from the `QMainWindow` but I cannot work out how the widget knows it no longer has focus so I can pause updates to the data, and given one of these views is video data I don't want it to be constantly updating in the background. Is it reasonable here for the `MainWindow` to just disconnect all signals, change the widget and then make new connections or is there a better Qt approach? I didn't necessarily want such tight coupling as the view itself knows what it should display on the buttons, not the main window.

I tried overriding `focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e)` in the children of the stacked widget but it is never called.

Answer (score 1):

Your `QStackedWidget` has a signal `currentChanged(int index)`, this signal is fired everytime the current displayed widget on the `QStackedLayout` changes, can't you use this signal to toggle a flag on the widget displaying video to not to render it?

Whent he currentWidget is the video widget you can resume the rendering of the data( imaghe ) supplied to it, else you can simply discard the data given to it and save CPU cycles by not rendering it?

Am I missing something here?